# ASP.NET Core Auth0 - Unable to unprotect the message.State

Tags: asp.net-core, auth0

We have Auth0 enabled for a site and it has been working well for quite some time.

All of a sudden when I enter the site and get redirected to Auth0 to enter my crendentials (and press login), I get faced with a screen with the following message.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   Exception: Unable to unprotect the message.State.
>
> MoveNext AggregateException: Unhandled remote failure.
>
> MoveNext

If I repeatedly refresh my site with `/signin-auth0` at the end of the url the same error screen is shown.

Now when I repeated all steps from start (meaning entering my site) it all of a sudden work. What's this error anyway?

Comment: My gut feeling is that this was very temporary, it would however be good to know the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This was resolved by the Auth0 team](https://auth0.com/forum/t/asp-net-core-signup-using-lock-error/3822/13?u=john_hoerr) as a bug in Auth0's transmission of the `state` parameter for social logins, notably Google. Things should be working normally again.

Comment: Yes the discussions in that thread seem to be just a couple of hours old, marking this as accepcted.